# How do I restrict a member's value to be <= another member?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the entity framework in MVC4, and I have the following domain class.

My problem is this, how do I restrict the value of SalePrice to be <= Price?  I have been searching for a suitable attribute that can do this but haven't found one.

EDIT:

Let's say a person enters $20.00 for a price value when preparing to submit a form, Then they enter a sale price of $25.00.  The program will disallow this because the sale price cannot be higher than the price of the item.  I am wondering if there is an `[Attribute]` that can enforce this restriction on SalePrice.

```
public class MedicalProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    // needs to be less than price.
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double SalePrice { get; set; }

    // is a foreign key
    public int BrandID { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you mean can you please explain better ?

Comment: @deathismyfriend I've edited the question to give a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a custom [`ValidationAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx) to do exactly what you require. The attribute would require the name of a propety to compare to, and a `ComparisonType`. I have created a very quick sample below:

#### ComparisonAttribute

```
public enum ComparisonType
{
    LessThan,
    LessThanOrEqual,
    Equal,
    GreaterThanOrEqual,
    GreaterThan,
    NotEqual
}

public sealed class ComparisonAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    string PropertyToCompare { get; set; }
    ComparisonType Type { get; set; }

    public ComparisonAttribute(string propertyToCompare, ComparisonType type)
    {
        PropertyToCompare = propertyToCompare;
        Type = type;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (validationContext.ObjectInstance == null || value == null)
            return new ValidationResult("Cannot compare null values");

        PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(PropertyToCompare);
        object propertyValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        string errorMessage = "";

        if (value is IComparable)
        {
            int compVal = ((IComparable)value).CompareTo(propertyValue);
            switch (Type)
            {
                case ComparisonType.LessThan:
                    errorMessage = compVal < 0 ? "" : string.Format("{0} is not less than {1}", validationContext.DisplayName, property.Name);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.LessThanOrEqual:
                    errorMessage = compVal <= 0 ? "" : string.Format("{0} is not less than or equal to {1}", validationContext.DisplayName, property.Name);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.Equal:
                    errorMessage = compVal == 0 ? "" : string.Format("{0} is not equal to {1}", validationContext.DisplayName, property.Name);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    errorMessage = compVal >= 0 ? "" : string.Format("{0} is not greater than or equal to {1}", validationContext.DisplayName, property.Name);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.GreaterThan:
                    errorMessage = compVal > 0 ? "" : string.Format("{0} is not greater than {1}", validationContext.DisplayName, property.Name);
                    break;
                case ComparisonType.NotEqual:
                    errorMessage = compVal != 0 ? "" : string.Format("{0} cannot be equal to {1}", validationContext.DisplayName, property.Name);
                    break;
                default:
                    errorMessage = "";
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
    }

}
```

#### Usage

```
public class Model
{
    [Comparison("Value2", ComparisonType.LessThanOrEqual)]
    public int Value1 { get; set; }

    public int Value2 { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could think about making `public double SalePrice { get; set; }` a more fully featured property with a backing field. You would then test for the value of `Price` before allowing `SalePrice` to be `set`. Here's a quick example:

```
private double _salePrice;

public double SalePrice
{
    get { return _salePrice; }
    set
    {
        // only set _salePrice if it's less than
        // or equal to Price
        if(value <= Price)
            _salePrice = value;
    }
}
```

give it a try...

**[Edit]** - i saw you changed the question a little, so to add to that, there is the `CompareAttribute` that can be used to validate two properties against each other (however, i'm *certain* this is restricted to string values - will confirm). Also, take a look at this page, this has a custom solution that looks nice and flexible and may work for you: http://forums.asp.net/t/1924941.aspx. gorra head - 00:43 in the UK!!

Comment: I will look into the `[CompareAttribute]`

Comment: It looks like you're right.  CompareAttribute is used for making sure one property is equal to another property exactly, and it is restricted to string values.

Comment: With the link you provided in your answer, I was able to find another link to a nuGet package called **MVC FoolProof Validation**, it expands upon the Attribute Validation provided in ASP.Net MVC.  it has attributes such as `[GreaterThanOrEqualTo(string property)]` and `[LessThan(string property)]`  Thank you.  here is the link: http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Comment: yeah, i did see that link and *knew* you'd be aware of it -so definitely a great find for you.